# how to bind gridview with dynamic column asp.net sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to bind gridview bu datasource. My SQL is works good. But it's manual right now. Like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Module]
             ,  [KPI_Name]
             ,  CAST([4] as VARCHAR(50)) AS Ay_1
             ,  CAST([5] as VARCHAR(50)) AS Ay_2
             ,  CAST([6] as VARCHAR(50)) AS Ay_3
             ,  CAST([7] as VARCHAR(50)) AS Ay_4
             ,  CAST([8] as VARCHAR(50)) AS Ay_5
             ,  CAST([9] as VARCHAR(50)) AS Ay_6  FROM [CorpApps].[dbo].[SPerf_Notes] WHERE ([Module] = @Module)
```

My Table's Column's names are [4] [5] [6] ... etc. How can I link column names to dynamic variable?

These are not working...

> CAST(@[EXP] as VARCHAR(50)) AS Ay_1

or

> CAST([@EXP] as VARCHAR(50)) AS Ay_1

or

> CAST(@[@EXP] as VARCHAR(50)) AS Ay_1

Thank you.

Comment: Put gridview html and code by which you are adding data to grid.

Comment: whaaat? i do not understand what you mean?

Comment: Dynamic variables may introduce SQL injection.